# Regexp to match groups containing optional parenthesis in the end of line

Tags: php, regex, ruby

I need to extract a law text in Portuguese with three parts: prefix, body, meta, something like this:

```
art. 3º Esta Consolidação estatui (teste 123) as normas que regulam as relações individuais. (abc 123)
```

```
PREFIX: "art. 3º"
BODY: "Esta Consolidação estatui (teste 123) as normas que regulam as relações individuais."
META: "(abc 123)"
```

I suspect I need something related to look-ahead, but cannot figure it out.

Here it is the regexp:

```
^([aA]rt\. \d+º?)(.*(?=\(.*\)))(\(.*\))?$
```

Here are the lines that should match:

```
art. 3º Esta Consolidação estatui as normas que regulam as relações individuais. (modificado pela lei 234/98) 
art. 3º Esta Consolidação estatui as normas que regulam as relações individuais. 
art. 3º Esta Consolidação estatui (teste 123) as normas que regulam as relações individuais. 
art. 3º Esta Consolidação estatui (teste 123) as normas que regulam as relações individuais. (abc 123)
```

My efforts are in this link: https://regex101.com/r/pPlOkn/3

I need to match all the variations (the four lines):
[image]

Comment: Not all the content contains those 3 parts. The second line has not part that ends with parenthesis. Try https://regex101.com/r/9EQetr/1

Comment: @Emma: almost.  See the second line of the image in my post, there are 3 groups, and parenthesis inside the text belong to the second group

Comment: @Thefourthbird, that's why the title says "optional parenthesis"

Comment: @FernandoFabreti Of course, I see. Do you mean that in your example link you only want to match the last 2 lines? https://regex101.com/r/pPlOkn/3 Or do you want to match all lines?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The regex needs to be in "the question itself" not in an image which forces us to recreate it from the image, or go to another site to copy/paste it just to help you. If you put it into the question we don't have to do those things. Also, if the link to the image breaks, your question will make no sense.

Comment: @theTinMan, sorry about that, I have corrected the question.

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to all inputs (e.g, `str = "art. 3º Esta...individuais. (abc 123)"`. That way readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it. That also makes it easier for readers to cut and paste. It would also be helpful to explicitly state the rule for determining when the prefix ends and when the meta begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that the forward lookahead in the middle effectively insists on the string having a `(...)` at the end of the line. By removing that lookahead, and changing the optional group at the end so that it can only match `(...)` with *no* intervening `)`, it should do what you want:

```
^([aA]rt\. \d+º?)\s*(.*?)\s*(\([^)]*\))?$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pPlOkn/7)

Comment: very good one.  Could you explain why a `?` is inside the second group? It looks like it does the magic.

Comment: @FernandoFabreti that makes the capture non-greedy, without it the second group would capture all the characters to the end of the line. See https://regex101.com/r/pPlOkn/5

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the prefix ends with a digit or with a digit followed by 'º', followed by one or more spaces.

```
str = "art. 3º Esta Consolidação estatui (teste 123) as normas que regulam as relações individuais. (abc 123)"
```

In this case I find it easier to split the string into three pieces rather than to extract the three strings desired.

```
prefix, body, meta = str.split(/(?<=º) +|\. +(?=\()/)

prefix #=> "art. 3º" 
body   #=> "Esta Consolidação estatui (teste 123)...individuais" 
meta   #=> "(abc 123)"
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more spaces immediately preceded by `'º'`, *or* (`'|'`) match a period followed by one or spaces, immediately followed by a left parenthesis. `'º'` and `'('`, being within a *positive lookbehind* and *positive lookahead*, respectively, are not part of the matches.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ruby, How would you think performance of splitting compares to matching?

Comment: I doubt it makes a great deal of difference, but I don't really know. If, however, the prefix always end with `'º'` there is a much faster way to do it. That's one reason why it's important to provide specific rules for where the prefix ends and the meta begins.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the faster way?

Comment: If the prefix always ends with `’º’`, you could write `i1 = str.index(‘º‘); i2 = str.rindex(‘(’); prefix = str[0,..i1]; body = str[i1+1..i2-1].strip; meta = str[i2..-1]`. If the prefix may end with a digit, *in which case* the body may not contain the character `’º’`, after finding `str.index(‘º‘) #=> nil` one could compute `i1 = str[/\D+\d+/].size-1`. this last regular expression matches one or more non-digits (`\D`) followed by one or more digits (`\d`)...

Comment: ...`str[i..j]` returns the substring of `str` that begins at index `i` and ends at index `j`. `str.index(s)` is the index of the start of the first occurrence of the string `s’ within the string `str`. `str.rindex(s)` is the same except it starts at the end of the string and works backwards.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, avoid regex altogether. Thanks.

Comment: I somehow mixed you up with the author of another question who said they didn’t know Ruby, which is why I included all that basic stuff in my last comment (which I’ll leave for the benefit of newbies).

Comment: No worries at all - always interesting to see how other languages express these constructs.

Comment: @Nick, all this time I was thinking you were the OP (in part because I’ve been writing these comments on a phone.) Oh, well.